# Is it possible to emulate JS's setTimeout in Sinatra / Synchrony?

Tags: ruby, node.js, timeout, sinatra

I'm possibly looking for an alternative to node.js - some really nice things about it are setTimeout() and setInterval().

I found that Sinatra has a [plugin called Synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) which looks like something I might actually use.

Is it reasonable to just make a new thread and have it do a busywait or something?